# The expected value and variance of E(-1X)?

Tags: probability, variance, expected-value

This might be a stupid question, but how I can calculate the expected value $\operatorname{E}(-1X)$ and variance $\operatorname{Var}(-1X)$ for example in a case in which $X\sim N(100,0.1^2)$?

Comment: Is it a homework?

Comment: A part of assignment. Other parts are clear but this keeps me stuck...

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties

Answer (score 1):

We have the general rules

$$
E[a + bX] = a + bE[X]
$$

and

$$
Var[a + bX] = b^2 Var[X]
$$

So in this case,

$$
E[-1X] = -1 \cdot 100 = -100
$$

and

$$
Var[-1X] = (-1)^2 \cdot 0.1^2 = 0.1^2
$$